# Selected files using Filechooser do not show up as selected when ran on Windows. Runs perfectly on OSX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX gui program that uses filechooser to select pdf's and then runs the program on the selected PDFS. I programed this on my Mac however one of my users is on windows. Everything works as intended on Mac, but when you click the select PDF button in the program on windows, the directory opens as expected but when you select the files and click ok, nothing is returned as selected.

```
 selectBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
        //Select PDF's Button
        System.out.println("SelectBtn"); //Press to select all ICP-MS PDF files you want to analyze

        //opens file directory to find and select PDF Files
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Select PDF Files");

        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("PDF Files", "*.pdf"));
        List<File> selectedFiles = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(savedStage);

        for (File selectedFile : selectedFiles) {  // gets all of the path's to selected files and saves them as a string
            String tempFilePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(tempFilePath);
            selStrings.add(tempFilePath);
        }

        //shortening up the listview path, need to update list view using this then add a button to increase or decrease the size of path
        for (int i= 0; i < selStrings.size(); i++) {
            String tempFilePath = selStrings.get(i);
            String result[] = tempFilePath.split("/");
            String slash = "/"; 
            String shortFilePath = result[result.length - 3] + slash + result[result.length - 2] + slash + result[result.length - 1];
            shortStrings.add(shortFilePath);
            System.out.println(shortFilePath);
        }

        Collections.sort(selStrings);
        Collections.sort(shortStrings);//sorts alphabetically for initial view in listview
        refreshListView();
    });
```

Any idea's what could be causing this? I was expecting JVM to work on both platforms without much though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use:

```
String slash = FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator();
String result[] = tempFilePath.split(slash);
String shortFilePath = result[result.length - 3] + slash + result[result.length - 2] + slash + result[result.length - 1];
```

This way you get the OS-independent Fileseparator character that definetely works for every Operating System. I think that windows doesn't like the normal '/' and is normally using '\' unlike MacOS X.

I hope I could help you :)

Comment: I will absolutely add that in! I didn't know that was a thing haha, thanks!